# The following code is showing error in AIX server but working fine in Red Hat server

Tags: regex, shell, grep, aix

```
string='binddn:cn=SxX.UXxxxM-E2A,OU=CA,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com'
```

The working peice of code in Red Hat

```
dn=($(grep -oi 'cn=[^():]*dc=com' <<< "$string"))
```

I modified the code for AIX and modified code is

```
dn=($(grep -xi 'cn=[^():]*dc=com' "$string"))
```

The code is working perfect in RedHat server, the output in redhat is

```
dn[0]="cn=SxX.UXxxxM-E2A,OU=CA,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com"
```

The error in AIX is

```
grep: can't open binddn:cn=SxX.UXxxxM-E2A,OU=CA,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com
```

**Edited:**

Another example:

```
string = "userbasedn:DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com?subtree?(&(objectcategory=person)(uidNumber=*)(|(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=example1,OU=GROUPS,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com)(memberOf:1.2.840.11.1.4.1941:=cn=example2,OU=GROUPS,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com)))
groupbasedn:DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com?subtree?(&(objectcategory=group)(gidNumber=*))"
```

expected output

```
dn[0]=cn=example1,OU=GROUPS,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com
dn[1]=cn=example2,OU=GROUPS,OU=AI INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`, try this:

```
echo "$string" | awk -F"cn=" 'NF>1{$0=tolower($0);for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,"dc=com)");print FS a[1]"dc=com"}}'
cn=example1,ou=groups,ou=ai infrastructure,dc=i,dc=companyname,dc=com
cn=example2,ou=groups,ou=ai infrastructure,dc=i,dc=companyname,dc=com
```

Comment: -o  is not working in AIX as it is not defined in IBM document.

ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/grep.htm

Comment: @KartikM Added an `awk` example.  Edit your post with the extra example, its not readable as a comment.

Comment: @KartikM If you can use `awk`

Comment: I've to store all the matching strings in array of strings 'dn' and there can be multiple matching strings(more than two) , moreover is this syntax of awk is supported in AIX server?

Comment: Yes it is working perfect but it lowers the case in array.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `grep` is a file name, not a string. AIX correctly reports that it cannot find a file with that name. You would get the same error on Red Hat if you tried the same command.

Unfortunately, the `-x` option doesn't do what you hope; it checks whether the entire line of input matches the regex. Again, you will find exactly the same behavior on Red Hat.
According to the [AIX `grep` manual page](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=grep&tf=2&of=AIX&sf=1) it supports the `-o` option just fine, though.

The Bash "here string" syntax `<<<"string"` is not available if you don't have Bash, but it is easy to rephrase portably:

```
printf '%s\n' "$string" |
grep -oi 'cn=[^():]*dc=com'
```

If you don't have `grep -o`, try with `sed`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$string" |
sed -n 's/.*\(cn=[^():]*dc=com\).*/\1/p'
```

This is not exactly the same, because the first `.*` is greedy. If you expect more than one match on a line, you will need a slightly more complex regex.

Comment: This is working perfect for Red Hat but will this work on AIX with same syntax?

Comment: I have strived to make this portable but I don't have an AIX system to test on. Try it and see?